# Get user profile image from instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am getting user profile image from Instagram follow [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started). I got the authorized code after giving the Instagram app id, secret key, and redirect URI then based on the authorized code I get an access token. Based on the access token got an Instagram user id and username.

**Here is the code**

```
$insta_username = $insta_response['username'];
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$insta_username.'/?__a=1'));
```

after this, I got this error

Message: file_get_contents(https://www.instagram.com/fakenamesofficial/?__a=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 -

Comment: HI @AhilKhan - have you tried to look up this error - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429 - that might suggest what is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try
$jsonData = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$insta_username.'/?__a=1');

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?